# Jquery: how to make something fade out when mouse is idle. When mouse moves again, It fadesIn!

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have a div called "#top". I would like it to fade out when the mouse is **idle** for 3 seconds.  When the mouse moves again, make it appear (fade, of course)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout), saving the return value somewhere (to cancel it with [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) when the mouse moves again):

```
var timer;
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }

    $('#top:visible').fadeIn();
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#top').fadeOut()
    }, 3000)
})
```

You'll want this inside `$(document).ready()` or the like.

Comment: This seems to sort of work for me, but it doesn't fade, and the element doesn't reappear on mouse move.