# JQuery: mousemove fade in/out element

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I have a video player page and want the playlist div to only fade in when the mouse is moving, and fade out if the mouse is idle for 3 seconds. The div's class is "fadeobject" and it's ID is ""video-chooser"

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean the mouse moves *anywhere* and not just over the relevant `<div>` apply a [`mousemove()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mousemove#fn) event handler to the page:

```
var fadeout = null;
$("html").mousemove(function() {
  $("div.fadeobject").stop().fadeIn("slow");
  if (fadeout != null) {
    clearTimeout(fadeout);
  }
  fadeout = setTimeout(hide_playlist, 3000);
});

function hide_playlist() {
  $("div.fadeobject").stop().fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Every time the mouse moves a timer is started to fade the div after three seconds and the previous timer (if there was one) is cancelled.

**Note:** the `stop()` isn't *strictly* required here but is recommended when dealing with multiple animations/effects.

**Edit:** fixed function name typo and updated setTimeout arguments so timeout call works.

Comment: No luck. (http://pastebin.com/f50026c62 apparently I cant put code in comments) am I missing something?
Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Doesn't setTimeout take the miliseconds second? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and it works well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.elementClass').fadeTo(0, '0.5').hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(350, '0.8');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

[Jquery: how to make something fade out when mouse is idle. When mouse moves again, It fadesIn!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565463/jquery-how-to-make-something-fade-out-when-mouse-is-idle-when-mouse-moves-again)