# Div reappears after fadeout on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a div which I want to fade in, when the mouse is moving. If the mouse is idle for about 3 seconds I then want the div to fade out.

It works, but there's a tiny problem. If you move the mouse again a couple of times right after the div has appeared and then let the mouse idle for 3 seconds, the div is sometimes fading in again, right after it has faded out. I have no idea why this is happening and why it only happens sometimes.

The script I'm using is from another thread on this post: [Jquery: how to make something fade out...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565463/jquery-how-to-make-something-fade-out-when-mouse-is-idle-when-mouse-moves-agai)

I've tried to reset `time` in the end of `setTimeout`-function with no luck.

### **Here's my code:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="object">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.object {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
var timer;
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }

    $('.object').fadeIn(300);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.object').fadeOut(300);
        time = 0;
    }, 3000);

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WTWT/7/)

Anyone who please can help me? :)

Comment: It's working just fine from my side

Comment: There is no problem found in your fiddle..

Comment: It appears that it's only sometimes it does it.

Comment: Who down voted this question? It's well structured.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want the fade to happen once you need a variable to keep track of whether or not its the first time.  I've added a boolean to the code:

```
var timer;
var first = true;
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
    if (first) {
        $('.object').fadeIn(300);

            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.object').fadeOut(300);
                timer = 0;
                first = false;
            }, 3000);
    }         
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WTWT/29/)

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for.
I want the div to appear every time you move the mouse. But if you move the mouse a couple of times after the div has appeared, the div appears again right after it has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be looking at: [Hover Intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

It handles problems with hovering over an element, then moving out, then back in etc. I've used it with much success on things like this. It also allows you to keep hover triggered when going over child elements so nesting becomes easier.